# AI transcription makes no sense. Native Brits wanted!

Tags: listening

Everyone. I'm preparing some listening video clip, and AI transcription fails, however.
[watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX85gWxotQ4&t=66s)

It is from 1:45-2:10, I can't get or understand very well.
What does "Tilly Bam Bam" mean? a family nickname or something else?
"I can't see no bush", But why "bush"? It is a local accent for "bus", or this is a school bus service?
And what are the children saying? I catch only the last "love you, Mom. Love you, Dad".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'Tilly bam-bam' is clearly a family nickname, and he says 'I can't see no bus'. Not 'bush'. Some of the people are talking in a strong Yorkshire accent; are you sure this is right for your learning programme?

Comment: Yes, I am. I need some real life speaking beyond class.

Comment: Many native speakers from England will struggle to hear all the childrens' speech. I say again - you have chosen a difficult task.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a transcription request.

Comment: Against. Language itself is all-around. AI is not a do-it-all master. As people outside, we really need sort of touch on the real life.

Comment: As a "listening exercise" this is super hard.  It may be interesting, but mostly as an exercise in what is not possible.  You expect a "transcription" but this is not possible, since the children's speech is, in part, incomprehensible. So there are two things to note.  The kids cope with not understanding every word and are able to function. Secondly, the adults adapt their accents. When they are talking "to camera" and when they are talking to the children, there is a significant difference in accent.  But no transcriptions. That's sort of pointless here.

Comment: It is also a good example of how to use context.  The man is waiting for a bus.  He looks around and says "I can't see no bus(h?)"  now even if the /sh/ should was made, I'd still think "bus" because he it fits the context.  This kind of pragmatic listening will help you greatly.

Comment: "Love you, **Mum**" as they're British!

Answer (score 1):

“Tilly-bum-bum” does sound like a pet name.  When the children are leaving, dad calls, “Tell me all about it, Tilly.”

In “I can't see no bus,” I don't hear “sh”, but the vowel is Northern (used also in words like *cup*).

I cannot make out anything else from the children at that point.

Comment: +1 Definitely no "sh" sound on the end of "bus".

Comment: AI gave me "I can't see no bush", so I was wandering if there was such a school bus service called "bush" in Yorkshire.

Comment: It's clearly 'bam-bam'.

Comment: @KevinCheng - he says that (teasingly) and then what do you see? A bus!